# Snake eating itself

Tags: geometry, soft-question

I came across [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=puKevC5boFg&ab_channel=RobClarkVenitox) video of a snake eating itself. My brain could not comprehend this thought at all, hence asking this (sorry if this is off-topic).

My questions are$-$

1. How far can the snake's tail go into it's mouth?
2. If the whole tail can be inserted in the snakes mouth, what will be the final state of the snake, will it collapse into a point?

Also, I think an animation might be helpful.

**The question title and tags are inappropriate as I don't know how to properly frame this question. Please edit them accordingly.**

Comment: Do you expect us to give a geometrical model of a snake? Does the snake have a width? If yes, can you imagine two straight conical snakes, one eating the other? The one eating the other, unless its mouth can be expanded, cannot fully eat the other. Besides, in real life, unless its skull is very bendable, I guess a snake cannot eat the back of its own head.

Comment: Similar: [mathematical limit for a ouroboros torus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1041922/318073)